# While Loop, Program Error

Tags: c#

Basically what the program is suppose to do is verify that the username that was entered (in previous code to  register) matches the username that is inputted right now. So the user is allowed 3 chances to get it correct, but instead the code is not breaking out of the loop. Can anyone see what is wrong/needs fixing?

//User Enters username, and then username is verified

```
    do
        { 

            Console.Write("Please enter your username: ");
            user_login = Console.ReadLine();


            if (user_login != username)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The username does not match the one in our database");
                Console.WriteLine("Please try again");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                count_user = +1;
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your username matches!");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                break;
            }

        } while (user_login != username && count_user < 3) ;
```

Comment: suppose to be a do loop, got cut at top

do { }

Comment: `count_user = +1;` should be `count_user += 1;`. Please use a local debugger rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: or even count_user++

Comment: Sorry about that, but thank you so much!

Comment: Where are you initializing username ?

Answer (score 1):

The way to get it to work is as @Ken Y-N said just change the count_user = +1 to count_user +=1; What is wrong with the first code is that every time instead of incrementing the variable count_user you are just constantly setting it to +1or basically positive 1. That is why it never leaves the loop.